# Problems with running multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Im making an multithread app where the user adds in 1 ingredient at a time to make a fruit salad. There is a max number of fruits allowed to be put into the bowl.

The code compiles and run, but the problem is that it is only running one thread (Apple). Strawberry has the same thread.sleep(1000) time as apple. I have tried changing strawberry's sleep to a different sleep time but it did not fix the problem.

Apple.java

```
public class Apple implements Runnable
{
    private Ingredients ingredient;

    public Apple(Ingredients ingredient)
    {   
        this.ingredient = ingredient;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try 
            { 
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                ingredient.setApple(6);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Ingredients.java

```
public interface Ingredients 
{
    public void setApple(int max) throws InterruptedException;
    public void setStrawberry(int max) throws InterruptedException;
}
```

FruitSalad.java

```
public class FruitSalad implements Ingredients
{
    private int apple = 0;
    private int strawberry = 0;

    public synchronized void setApple(int max) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        if(apple == max)
            System.out.println("Max number of apples.");
        else
        {
            apple++;
            System.out.println("There is a total of " + apple + " in the bowl.");
        }
    }
    //strawberry
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main 
{
       public static void main( String[] args )
       {
           Ingredients ingredient = new FruitSalad();

           new Apple(ingredient).run();
           new Strawberry(ingredient).run();   
       }
}
```

Output:

- There is a total of 1 apple in the bowl.
- ....
- There is a total of 6 apple in the bowl.
- Max number of apples.

Comment: that's because you're failing to run these in separate threads..you're running both in the current thread, which is going to cause them to be executed sequentially.

Comment: How do i run them on seperate threads?

Comment: Furthermore I would recommend having the fruitsalad reference the ingredients, not the other way around. This is standard practice; many to one is better than one to many.

Comment: @user2273278, Quick fix would be `new Thread(new Apple(ingredient)).start();` and `new Thread(new Strawberry(ingredient)).start();`

Comment: Isn't it good practice to `join` the threads or is that unnecessary in Java?

Comment: @gzm0, `Thread#join` is a blocking mechanism. It's good if you want the threads to execute sequentially, and if that's the case here, why use threads at all?

Comment: @mre I rather meant using `join` to wait on all threads (once you've started them) and de-allocate resources. Or in this case to make sure that the main-thread does not terminate. So usage pattern would be: `t1.start(); t2.start(); t1.join(); t2.join;`.

Comment: @Christian Stewart, i used the concept as database design which only has 1 to many relationships. is it better to do it the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the `.run()` method on a Runnable directly within another thread, you simply add that "thread" to the same stack (i.e. it runs as a single thread).

You should instead wrap the Runnable in a new thread and use `.start()` to execute the thread.

```
Apple apple = new Apple(ingredient);
Thread t = new Thread(apple);
t.start();


Strawberry strawberry = new Strawberry(ingredient);   
Thread t2 = new Thread(strawberry);
t2.start();
```

You're still calling the run() method directly. Instead, you have to call the `start()` method, which calls `run()` indirectly in a new thread. See edit.

Comment: Instead of edit fighting, in the future I recommend simply rolling back your edit :)

Comment: Well, yes, because it only creates an apple; You'll then have to create a Strawberry and call `start()` on it the same way.

Comment: @ChristianStewart: haha sorry, that's the first time I've been in a situation like that. Duly noted :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing that instead:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Apple(ingredient));
t1.start;

Thread t2 = new Thread(new Strawberry(ingredient));
t2.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your classes extend `Thread`:

```
public class Apple extends Thread
public class Strawberry extends Thread
```

Then you can start those threads:

```
Apple apple = new Apple(ingredient);
Strawberry strawberry = new Strawberry(ingredient);   

apple.start();
strawberry.start();
```

You should call join on both threads to wait for them before terminating:

```
apple.join();
strawberry.join();
```